# $\sin\left(ax + \frac{\pi}{6}\right)$, find $a$ with given slope

Tags: trigonometry, parametric

I was given a function
$$y = \sin\left(ax + \frac{\pi}{6}\right)$$
In the point $x = \frac{\pi}{12}$, the slope of the tangent line of that point is $\frac a2$.

I need to find $a$ if it's given that $1 \lt a \lt 4$.

---

I found the derivative of $y$, assigned the $x$ and compared it to the slope.
So at the end, if I did all the steps correctly, I get that
$$\frac 12 = \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{12}a + \frac{\pi}{6}\right)$$

I thought about using the identity of
$$ \cos(\alpha + \beta) = \cos\alpha \cos\beta - \sin\alpha \sin\beta$$
But didn't help.
My biggest problem is that I don't know how to use the information that $1 \lt a \lt 4$.

Comment: To get "$\cos$" upright, you can use `\cos`. Same for `\sin`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $1<a<4$, then

$$\frac{\pi}{4}<\frac{\pi}{12}a + \frac{\pi}{6}<\frac{\pi}{2}$$

Since $\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{12}a + \frac{\pi}{6}\right)=\frac{1}{2}$ it follows

$$\frac{\pi}{12}a + \frac{\pi}{6}=\frac{\pi}{3}$$

Hence, $$a=2$$

Comment: Why is it exactly $\frac{\pi}{3}$ and not for example, $\frac{3\pi}{10}$? (Despite that the answer is correct).

Comment: @PichiWuana:
I don´t understand the question. There is only one real number $t$ in the interval $\left(\frac{\pi}{4},\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$ such that $\cos t=\frac{1}{2}$, namely $t=\Cos^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)=\frac{\pi}{3}$ because $\cos$ is monotone decreasing in that interval. Thus $$\frac{\pi}{12}a+\frac{\pi}{6}=\frac{\pi}{3}$$

Comment: Oh, I understood. Thanks.